# How to find a bool value in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a bool array.

`var arr = [true, false, true,false, true]`

My requirement:

If the array contains a bool value `true` I want to show a single alert 'array contains a true value'. Alert should not be multiple.
Can someone suggest how to achieve it in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Soumya, Please note that SO is **not get code for free** site. You have to try first and if you end up with some problem, share the problem with your attempt and we will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will do

```js
var arr = [true, false, true,false, true]
if(arr.includes(true)){
alert("true found");
}
```

Comment: Should we not close it as dupe instead?

Answer (score 4):

you can use [**Array.prototype.some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this purpose also.

```
var arr = [true, false, true,false, true]
if(arr.some((elem)=> elem === true))
{
 console.log('contains true')
}
```

You can also use [**Array.prototype.findIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method. If not found it will return -1.

```
if(arr.findIndex(elem=>elem === true)!=-1){
    console.log('contains true')
}
```

[**Object.is ( )**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)  uses `===` internally. So you can use it as well

```
if(arr.some(elem=>Object.is(elem,true))){
   console.log('contains true')
}
```

[**array.prototype.indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)  also uses `===` internally.

```
if(arr.indexOf(true) != -1){
   console.log('contains true')
}
```

There are so many ways to choose from.Pick the one that suits your need.

Comment: First, you should use `===` instead of `==`. Second, you can use `arr.some(x => x === true)`. No need to manually create a block and return if there is only 1 line. Third, its not a good practice to have looping mechanism as condition in `if`. Better save it in variable and use it.

Comment: you can use == because you are comparing things with the same type, also you can use arr.some(x => x), and the condition inside the if its evaluated before the if

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa `==` tries to convert to a string and compare but `true == 'true'` is false so adding `==` is, in my POV, wrong. Using `x=>x` is also not idea as OP explicitly wants to check for `true` and not thuthy value. Third, *condition inside the if its evaluated before the if* its obvious. But the point is it falls under bad conventions, at least for me. There is a level below which brevity results in loss of readability. You should maintain a balance. Code should be short but also be readable.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks for pointing this out. I should've used strict equality operator in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]){
        alert("Array contains a true value");
        break;
    }
}
```

OR

```
var b = false;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    b = b || arr[i];

if(b) 
    alert("Array contains a true value");
```

Comment: there are plenty of convenient built in methods in javascript that can serve this purpose well instead of using plain for loop. For loop shouldn't be used so frequently in javascript code as it reduces readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use Array.prototype.some, Following is the code.

```
let arr = [true, false, true,false, true]
if(arr.some(e=>e))
  alert("true is included in the array");
```

Comment: Did you check other answers if this approach is covered or not?

Comment: It was covered. But this code is more concise. Therefore thought of adding.

Comment: Please refer my comments under that answer. Also, if there is a concise way for someone's answer, its always better to comment it under it. Adding another answer is duplicating the content.